# Barriers - how to be sure that a write operation on a register has been completed?

Tags: arm, arm64, memory-barriers

I need to initialize an interrupt controller (GICv3), ARM. To do it, I need to set some registers, but only after initializing register `CTLR`. I must be sure that `CTLR` register has been written completely before doing other writing operations.

To do it, I found the [arm memory barriers](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0489/c/arm-and-thumb-instructions/miscellaneous-instructions/dmb--dsb--and-isb). In order to guarantee the behaviour, I though to operate as follows:

```
/* write CTLR
* isb()
* dmb();
* writing the other registers */
```

I am not expert in this domain and I am not sure to properly understood barriers: does the combination of `isb` and `dmb` can guarantee the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not enough to guarantee it.
Barriers do not mean that the receiving device (in this case, GICv3) has actually received the command and that you the register writing is finished.
You need to manually check it (e.g., [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/irqchip/irq-gic-v3.c#L204)).

Comment: Registers of interrupt controller are mapped into memory space. Your writing into memory, is same as writing into registers. `dmb` between 2 writes guarantee that second write would be issued after first one. GIC (or any other peripheral device) taking time to deal with changing state after writing `CTLR` register is totally different problem.

Comment: As a side note, mapping peripheral memory as `Device`, save you with dealing with sync barriers

Comment: Nice catch. So, the point is that "`dmb` between 2 writes guarantee that second write would be issued after first one", but no guarantees that the first one will be completed before the second one, or yes?

Comment: Wording is important in this case. Say there is sequence of writing: `wr1`, `dmb`, `wr2`. `wr1` is guaranteed to be issued before `wr2` and guaranteed to be completed before `wr2` is completed just by a fact that `wr1` is  issued first. `wr1` is not guaranteed to be *completed* before `wr2` is *issued*. If you need guarantee that `wr1` is completed, than there is `DSB` instruction for that.

Comment: Now in terms of setting up peripheral devices like GIC. Device might take time (more than a single clock) to finish some job. So for example you set bit `Reset` in `CONTROL` register and it takes 50 cycles to perform this peripheral device Reset. Normally the sequence would be set `Reset` bit in `CONTROL` register and poll `Ready` bit in `STATUS` register (Ready bit is set when reset is finished). That's probably what you want to do and that has very little if any with barriers. And make sure you work with 'Device' mapped memory. Otherwise `write CTLR` might stay in cache even with `dmb`